# Two types of JSON response (Python)

Tags: python, json

The JSON responses in question are [Police API](http://data.police.uk/api/leicestershire/neighbourhoods) and [Iceland's Flight Info API](http://apis.is/flight?language=en&type=departures). I'm easily able to parse the Police API but I'm struggling with the Iceland API.

The two responses are in a slightly different format as you can see:

```
{
    results: [
        {
        date: "14. Mar",
        flightNumber: "WW201",
        airline: "WOW air",
        to: "London Gatwick",
        plannedArrival: "07:00",
        realArrival: "12:14",
        status: "Departed 12:05"
    },
```

The top one is the one I'm struggling with, the one below is fine.

```
[
    {
        id: "C01",
        name: "New Parks"
    },
```

They seem to reverse the square and curly brackets, is there any reason for this? Pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 0):

This is really just up to the implementor of the API, but it's no big deal.  Essentially you can imagine the `results` property of the first one being the entire body of the second one:

```
# Access the first ID
data.results[0].id # Iceland
data[0].id         # Police
```